# Eclipse Plugin and ADT modification for API Integration in Create Project menu

Tags: android, eclipse, api, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I plan to create a plugin that is relevant to API integration for Android projects. Where i would be able to check/mark API's which i want to add and it should add all the relevant files and integrate the example in the Main_Activity / or the default activity which user creates.

As a **starter** i need to know that:

> 1) Do i need to start studying eclipse code or ADT Plugin only?
>
> 2) Is there is any such plugin already available?
>
> 3) Which category of the ADT i need to start learning such that i can
>   start working from it in the Create android project menu?

So far i have started checking the ADT code. Nothing is on web so i can't tell you what i have done.

Comment: Since the ADT Plugin is all but deprecated by Google, IMHO you would be **far** better served either creating your own Web-based generator (think [Android Bootstrap](http://www.androidbootstrap.com/), your own Gradle plugin (possibly in conjunction with something for Android Studio), or work on [the Andmore project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore) (the Eclipse Foundation's plan for a long-term Eclipse-based Android IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that you should know:

1) ADT Plugin is Deprecated; However

2) NO such thing already exists like what you want.

3) Android Creates Project using Templates like this
[image: This is a template from the ADT Plugin]

So, If you want to add an example to the code. There are two ways

- Have your own mini language so that the example integration code be generated
- Have predefined templates like Google already have

4) Before you start from the [ADT Plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/) you need to understand [THIS](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html).

5) Better add [Windows Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to Eclipse JDT environment (The one you require for Development).

6) You may also need to understand the working of `NewProjectCreator` in adt before you start doing the filing thing in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I see that New Project Wizard is implemented in the IDE Plugin. The source is available here: [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/)/ You may want to look into the code and the templates folder for more details